# Movie 65923 won't open or delete

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, bittorrent

I torrented a bunch of movies last week, but there was one within the group that didn't have a name. I did not think much of it as it was downloading, since I was torrenting a few obscure titles. When I went to open it earlier this afternoon, it would not play on any program on my laptop. It was saved as an MPEG file, so I downloaded a codec from the Microsoft store to play it, and still, no dice. I googled the title it provided - movie 65923 - to try and see what movie it even was, and it said that it was probably malware and I should get rid of it. However, when I go to delete it, a message comes up saying another program has opened the file, so I should close that program and try again. I closed every program on my laptop and still, no success. I even did the Windows key + R + %temp% trick, deleted everything there, and nothing changed.
What can I do?

I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Do a *full* check for malware both with your current AV suite and another, e.g. free [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download/), to be sure.
2. Check what process is locking this file. [LockHunter](https://lockhunter.com/). also free, not only shows what's locking it, but should be able to delete immediately or at the next restart.
3. If these fail, you may need to do a full scan when [booting from rescue media](https://www.lifewire.com/free-bootable-antivirus-tools-2625785), e.g. USB or CD.

*Some malware is so persistent, the only safe thing to do is to format the HDD and restore from an image.* [And some *really* nasty stuff might survive that!]